# Deleting an Object after collision

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode

I am making a game, and part of the game is a rabbit collecting eggs. I am having an issue with when the rabbit intersects the egg the game is crashing. the error I am getting is **Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x17805eed0> was mutated while being enumerated.'**

I have an image of 1 egg, and the egg appears after every couple of seconds, when the rabbit intersects the egg, I just want the egg to disappear and give 1 point.

Here is the code I am using

In the header file I have

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *eggs;
```

and the implementation file I have this for adding the egg

```
UIImageView *egg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth([[self gameView] frame]), holeBottom - 115 , 50, 60)];

[egg setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"easterEgg.png"]];
[[self gameView] insertSubview:egg belowSubview:[self counterLabel]];
[[self eggs] addObject:egg];
```

And this for detecting collision and trying to remove the egg

```
for (UIView *egg in [self eggs]) {
    [egg setFrame:CGRectOffset([egg frame], [link duration]*FBSidewaysVelocity, 0)];
    if ( CGRectIntersectsRect (rabbit.frame, CGRectInset ([egg frame], 8, 8))) {
       [[self eggs]removeLastObject];
       [self incrementCount];   
    }
 }
```

I'm hoping you can see where I have gone wrong with this code and help me to rectify the problem.

Thank you in advance for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error message if very clear that you cannot mutable collection (e.g. remove element) while enumerating it (e.g. using `for in` loop)

the easiest solution is to copy the collection and enumerate the copied one

```
for (UIView *egg in [[self eggs] copy]) { // <-- copy
    // you can modify `[self eggs]` here
}
```

or

```
NSMutableArray *tobeRemoved = [NSMutableArray array];
for (UIView *egg in [self eggs]) {
    if (condition)
        [tobeRemoved addObject:egg];
}

[[self eggs] removeObjectsInArray:tobeRemoved];
```

Answer (score 1):

`Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x17805eed0> was mutated while being enumerated` is being caused because you are looping over an array, while at the same time deleting the objects in that array. There are a few ways to get around this, one way is to create a new array of the objects that you want to delete while looping over the original array `eggs` and after the loop is finished, looping over this new array and performing the remove.

Code example:

```
NSMutableArray *eggs;//this is full of delicious eggs

//...

NSMutableArray *badEggs = [NSMutableArray array];//eggs that you want to removed will go in here

for(NSObject *egg in [self eggs]){
   if([egg shouldBeRemoved]){//some logic here
        [badEggs addObject:egg];//add the egg to be removed
   }
}


//now we have the eggs to be removed...

for(NSObject *badEggs in [self badEggs]){
    [eggs removeObject:badEgg];//do the actual removal...
}
```

**note**: your line of code `[[self eggs]removeLastObject];` looks like a mistake in any case... this removes the object at the end of the array (I don't think you want to do this...)